# Error occurs in CPanel site when calling livewire actions

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8 with livewire to create a website.

It works fine until I migrate it to CPanel.

I followed the guide from YouTube to split the whole directory into 2 parts, public_html/shop/v1 contains the public directory with index.php, and public_html/shop_main contains all the codes and files.

It shows this error but I fix it by adding the line 'asset_url'  => 'http://myhost.com/shop/v1', in config/livewire.php.

[Uncaught ReferenceError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVg4g.png)

Then I encounter another problem with livewire. The error occurs when i try to change the combo box value which bind to livewire public property.

[New error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhTFN.png)

I hardly find any references online regarding this error. By the way, livewire-products is the livewire component to show the product.

I would appreciate any help from experts here.

Comment: Anyone know what when wrong? I really need to get it running as soon as possible, goggling don't give much on this error.

Comment: Any help that I can get?

Comment: hello. Anybody's here that can help?